# Trading Terminal Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, charts, analysis, stock

this is my first question here. I am trying to create an app for chart analysis in Objective-C.
Is there a good solution to show a stock chart in a view and at the same time be able to draw lines on this chart.
Just like in this picture shown: http://gb2007.deutsche-euroshop.de/des/annual/2007/gb//German/60/30/grafik_1_chartanalyse.gif

I am pretty new to programming and doing this exercise for a school project.
Feel free to present every solution i really need the right idea to succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the "go to" solution (in other words, the one everyone runs to) is CorePlot, which you can find on GitHub at:

https://github.com/core-plot

And there's a [RayWenderlich tutorial on stock charts with CorePlot](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2), however his (or their) tutorials are more geared for iOS so you may have to do a bit of adjusting to make things work with MacOS.  At least you'll be in the same neighborhood (using Objective-C, CorePlot, etc.).

I suspect any solution is going to be a bit "heavy" (or too much) for you to consider as a new programmer.  Graphics & plotting within an app can be really intimidating, and you should try to get a couple other projects under your belt and in your portfolio first.

Comment: Thank you first of all! I hoped there would be a simplier solution but ok so that´s a target aim at for the next year or even longer. I will try to inform me in the direction of CorePlot. Really hoped there would be an alternative to CorePlot for Mac. :(